# How to set number as a key value in an array using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, grouping

I want to get the following output below. I am using a foreach to do the following but it is not printing the number. Instead of getting '0', '1', or '2', i am getting a blank ''.

How would I print the array as expected?

```
$results = array (
  array(
   'body' => 'somevalue1',
   'title' => 'somevalue1',
   'type' => 'foo'
  ),
  array(
    'body' => 'somevalue2',
    'title' => 'somevalue2',
    'type' => 'foo'
  ), 
  array(
    'body' => 'somevalue3',
    'title' => 'somevalue3',
    'type' => 'bar'
  ),
  array(
    'body' => 'somevalue4',
    'title' => 'somevalue4',
    'type' => 'foobar'
  ),
  array(
    'body' => 'somevalue5',
    'title' => 'somevalue5',
    'type' => 'foobar'
  ),
  array(
    'body' => 'somevalue6',
    'title' => 'somevalue6',
    'type' => 'foobar'
  ),
);
```

Desired output:

```
$values = array(
    'foo' => array(
        [0] => array(
            'body' => 'some value',
            'title' => 'some value'
         ),
         [1] => array(
             'body' => 'other value',
             'title' => 'other value'
         )
     ),
     'bar' => array(
        [0] => array(
            'body' => 'some value',
            'title' => 'some value'
         )
     ),
     'foobar' => array(
        [0] => array(
            'body' => 'some value',
            'title' => 'some value'
         ),
         [1] => array(
             'body' => 'other value',
             'title' => 'other value'
         ),
        [2] => array(
             'body' => 'other value',
             'title' => 'other value'
         )
     ),
);
```

Code:

```
$value_index = array(); //used to keep track of number of values under field1
foreach($results as $row) {
   //get number of field1's. if none, then set to 0
   $num = isset($value_index[$row.type]) ? $value_index[$row.type] : 0;
   /* performs some logic here */

    //store values in temp array
    $temp['body'] = $row.body;
    $temp['title'] = $row.title;

   $values[$row.type][$num] = $temp;

    $value_index[$row.type] = $num + 1;
}//end foreach
```

Current problem:

- $values[$row.type][$num] = $temp;
- the $num is not saving '0', '1', etc. it is saving it as ''

Goal:

- Group all the types together. For example, for the type=foo, i want to group them in a way that I can later print them by types. So i would want to print all elements where type=foo and i want to be able to access them via '0', '1', '2', etc if there are many elements in that grouped array.

Comment: wats the desired output? its not clear from the code

Comment: why you have 'foo' = instead of =>

Comment: @user2951257 where is this coming from `$results`? Please post it also

Comment: You have a lot of typo.

Instead of using `=` in array use `=>`

And in your foreach loop replace `.` with `->`

Comment: @Bluetree i have added more details and reformatted in hopes of making it clear.

Comment: @nogad i had originally included the desired output where i tried to highlight that instead of getting '0', '1', etc by using $num variable i am getting '', '', (blank values). Either way i have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let php automatically index your arrays by using `[]` in your iterated declarations.  `array_slice()` is the concise way to extract the first two elements with their keys, but if you like micro-optimization you can type it all out.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5WFOM))

```
foreach($results as $a){
    $output[$a['type']][]=array_slice($a,0,2);
    //or faster&more verbose: $output[$a['type']][]=['body'=>$a['body'],'title'=>$a['title']];
}
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'foo' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'body' => 'somevalue1',
      'title' => 'somevalue1',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'body' => 'somevalue2',
      'title' => 'somevalue2',
    ),
  ),
  'bar' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'body' => 'somevalue3',
      'title' => 'somevalue3',
    ),
  ),
  'foobar' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'body' => 'somevalue4',
      'title' => 'somevalue4',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'body' => 'somevalue5',
      'title' => 'somevalue5',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'body' => 'somevalue6',
      'title' => 'somevalue6',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: there may be scenarios where there are more than 3 elements so I went with $output[$a['type']][]=['body'=>$a['body'],'title'=>$a['title']];